# how to stop / kill and start a process in aws ebs using .ebextensions ?

Tags: django, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried using the following .ebextensions :     commands:

```
    01-kill:

        command:        "kill $(pgrep -flvx auto_pilot.py | grep auto_pilot.py)"

        ignoreErrors:        true

    02-wget:

        command:        "python /opt/python/current/app/phoenix_app/auto_pilot.py &"
```

Comment: EBS == Elastic Block Store. Not Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: What was the result of that try, and where are you stuck now?

Comment: After running the above script We didn't find auto_pilot.py running in the background. If I don't add "ignoreErrors" its not deploying.